# How to add MultiColumn Header for ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview with two columns, and I want to add "Name" and "Age" headers for them, please kindly help me. Thank you.

Is that possible to use addHeaderView()?

main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"        
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"        
    android:layout_width="match_parent"        
    android:layout_height="match_parent"        
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"        
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"        
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"        
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"        
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >        

    <TextView        
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"        
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />        

</RelativeLayout>
```

listview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Relativelayout01"
    android:paddingBottom="4dip"
    android:paddingLeft="12dip">

<TextView
        android:text="Name"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:text="Age"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/age"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/name"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/name">
    </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

DbHelper.java

```
package com.myapp3;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME ="bebook_db";

    public DbHelper(Context context){
            super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,1);
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE mytable(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Name TEXT,Age INTEGER); ");

            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

            cv.put("Name", "Anna");
            cv.put("Age", 19);
            db.insert("mytable", "Name", cv);

            cv.put("Name", "Jane");
            cv.put("Age", 21);
            db.insert("mytable", "Name", cv);

            cv.put("Name", "Mary");
            cv.put("Age", 17);
            db.insert("mytable", "Name", cv);
    }

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable");
            onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.myapp3;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private SQLiteDatabase  db = null;
    private Cursor cursor = null;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       db= (new DbHelper (getApplicationContext())).getWritableDatabase();        
       cursor =db.rawQuery("SELECT _id,Name, Age from mytable ORDER BY Age", null);

       adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                       R.layout.listview, 
                       cursor, 
                       new String[]{"Name","Age"},
                       new int[]{R.id.name, R.id.age},1);
       setListAdapter(adapter);

}

protected void onDestroy() {
       super.onDestroy();
       cursor.close();
       db.close();
}

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            return true;
    }

    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,  ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it’s just because you don’t apply a View field a proper value.
You see I never develop for Android platform,
but the top one lines is like XAML in WPF.
So if they similar I suggest you to try something like this.

```
<ListView Name="listView1" Height="246" Width="640"
VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="33,86,0,0">
   <ListView.View>
      <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="500" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="year" Width="100" />
      </GridView>
   </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```